# single quoting values using sql to create macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am using a macro in SAS to loop over the data tables in a specific library. I put the metadata information in a data null step and make a comparison with a where statement and my macro variable.

My SQL step looks like:

```
proc sql;
  select quote(trim(code)) into :procedures separated by ', ' from procedures;
quit;
```

Some values of `code` contain values like "45.10" and "G0102", so cannot be coerced to numeric. The macro contains the line:

```
%macro filter_codes(indata, outdata);
  data &outdata;
     set &indata(where = (code in (&procedures)));
  run;
%mend;
```

but the decimal values create an issue when double-quoted using the "quote" function.

Can I separate values with single quotes?

EDIT: The issue was caused by the fact that the filter_codes macro was run within a call execute step (over a range of datasets) and double quotes resolved in macro variables inside of double quotes would end the call execute.

Comment: There's nothing explicitly wrong with your code, unless your values contain the quotation marks themselves.  There's certainly nothing different in how SAS uses `'` from `"` except in macro variable resolution, which doesn't seem relevant here from your question.  A simple test on my side proved it to work fine, using `height` from `sashelp.class`.  Can you post some example data that shows this not working?

Comment: You're correct, the reason why this caused an error was that the quoted text was resolved within a call execute command in a data _null_ step. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
  select catt("'", code, "'") into :procedures separated by ', ' from procedures;
quit;
```

Also fix the where option in set statement:

```
set &indata(where=(code in (&procedures)));
```

Comment: The solution is rather obvious, though not as elegant as a "quote" command. I did effectively the same thing by called `select "'" || code || "'" into ...`.

Answer (score 2):

How about in one step using SQL?

```
%macro filter_codes(indata, outdata);
  proc sql ;
    create table &OUTDATA as
    select * from &INDATA
    where code in(select distinct code from procedures) ;
  quit ;
%mend;
```

No need to worry about quoting then.

Answer (score 1):

In 9.3 you have a second argument, enabling you to use single quotes in the `quote()` [function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p059exu866hqw2n0zw9aoxf3p6oj.htm).

```
proc sql noprint;
select quote(trim(code),"'") into :procedures separated by ', ' from procedures;
```

However..  Am not a fan of this function as it pads empty character variables with a single space (see below).

```
data _null_;
  x=''; /* empty */
  y=quote(x,"'");
  put y=;  /* gives y=' ' */
run;
```

Unfortunately it's the only 'in built' way (other than a proc export or suchlike) to get reliable quoting applied (eg quoting the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue where you reference the variable.  Sounds like you were trying to use something like

```
call execute("set &indata(where=(code in (&procedures)))") ;
```

First there is no need to use double quotes in the CALL EXECUTE string. Push the &procedures onto the command stack unresolved.

```
call execute('set &indata(where=(code in (&procedures)))') ;
```

If you did want to resolve the macro variable then look at using %sysfunc(quote()).

```
put %sysfunc(quote(The procedure list is &procedures));
```